# Add DELETE to query that returns duplicate records | SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, duplex

i need your help.

I've this query that detect a duplex records:

```
SELECT
    name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

So i need to delete the results, so i've try this:

```
Delete FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

but doesn't work. Could tell me an help ? thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [query](https://morecoding.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/duplicate-rows/):

```
DELETE
FROM users
WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM users
GROUP BY name, email)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no ID Column (Primary Key) in your question, assuming there is no ID column.
So below CTE will delete duplicate records.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT name
, email
, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by name, email Order by(Select 1)) as Sno
FROM users
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE SNO>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to **JUST** remove the duplicate rows not all the rows relating to the duplicate rows.

You can use ROW_NUMBER here.  You haven't provided the whole schema for the `USERS` table so here's an example

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users(
     Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,[Name] NVARCHAR(50)
    ,eMail NVARCHAR(50)
    ,DateCreated DATETIME
)

SELECT
     Id
    ,[Name]
    ,eMail
    ,DateCreated
    ,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Name, eMail ORDER BY DateCreated ASC)  
FROM dbo.Users
```

you can change this query to a Common Table Expression and then you can DELETE from it

```
;WITH cteDups
AS(
    SELECT
         Id
        ,[Name]
        ,eMail
        ,DateCreated
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Name, eMail ORDER BY DateCreated ASC)  
    FROM dbo.Users
)
DELETE FROM cteDups WHERE RN > 1
```

The `RN > 1` will remove the duplicate records only